# bot discord python message with commands

Tags: python, bots, discord

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_role("Administrator")
async def mp(ctx, message):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(message)`
```

Hello, I do not know why but it does not take all the arguments, it puts only the first word and not those behind

Answer (score 0):

This is how the `commands` module works, the message will be split into words and fed to your function separately. As per [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters), you can put quotes around words to have them arrive as a single argument.

If you want the full message, you can get it as `ctx.message.content`